# pip install pyzmq in a virtualenv on windows7

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv

On my Windows7 (64bit) computer, I installed Python 2.7 from python.org and did a pip install of ipython, pyzmq, jinja2, and tornado in order to use the notebook. I also installed numpy and scipy, which at some point required to install a C++ compiler (I used VCForPython27). Everything worked just fine. Then, I did a pip install of virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper-win. I created a test virtualenv, with "mkvirtualenv test", and inside it I did "pip install ipython", which worked, but then "pip install pyzmq" failed with the message: "error: unable to find vcvarsall.bat". I did some research and the suggestions I found involve installing other software, such as a C++ compiler, which I already did. My question is, why do I need to do that? pyzmq was installed without problems from the "root" python install, but for some reason I cannot pip-install it inside virtualenvs. Perhaps some important environment variable is gone when workon test is called? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to find where vcvarsall.bat is located on your computer.  Check your path environment variable to see if that directory is there.  Then, check path as it stands inside your virtualenv, and see if activating your virtualenv removed that directory from your path.

Comment: The only difference in the paths is the inclusion of the virtualenv directory up front. Added the path to vcvarsall.bat in the path environment variable, but still get the error message.